Mesh appears in renders but is not visible in object mode/viewport render (Blender 4.1)
It seems many problems people have with Blender are objects appearing in object mode and not in their renders, in my case it's the total opposite.
My mesh in made visible in the side bar and in object properties everything is set to default, however my mesh does not seem to appear in my view port, no matter the engine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!



Try Alt-H with the cursor in the 3D View?

@JohnEason No, it is not hidden, that's Local view and obviously the object in question is not included.

You are in Local view, indicated by the (Local) in the top left of the 3D Viewport.
You switch to local view by pressing Numpad / and then only those objects are visible which were selected at the time you switched.
Selecting or deselecting objects while you are in local view does not make them visible if they were not in the selection for local view (you can however still hide and unhide the ones that are there.
To get back to the normal view, just press Numpad / again. You can use local view to focus on a certain object for editing without having to hide and unhide other objects. Also rotating the view, zooming in and out or changing to different shading like Solid, Material Preview etc. is limited to the local view and once you get back, the viewport is as it was before switching.


Good catch! I missed that because everything except the missing character must have been selected when he went into Local view. It's more usually used with a single object.

@JohnEason Yep, it is usually used with a single object... but I guess this was not usage but an accident, so probably the intention was to do something completely different...
